# protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an object with such values as

```
%{"Friday" => [], "Monday" => [], "Saturday" => [], "Sunday" => ["3:0-4:0", "6:0-7:0"], "Thursday" => [], "Tuesday" => [], "Wednesday" => []}
```

I wanted to show it in my email template's view, i just stated as

```
<p>Schedule: <%= @schedule %></p>
```

I got this error on it

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{"Friday" => [], "Monday" => [], "Saturday" => [], "Sunday" => ["3:0-4:0", "6:0-7:0"], "Thursday" => [], "Tuesday" => [], "Wednesday" => []}
```

What will be the best way to show it in HTML?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot directly output a Map like that; only things that implement the `Phoenix.HTML.Safe` protocol. If you want to print what `iex` would print (which is Elixir syntax if possible), you can explicitly call `inspect` to convert the Map into a String, and then output that:

```
<p>Schedule: <%= inspect @schedule %></p>
```

If you want to print it in a different way, you can use `for`:

```
<p>
  Schedule: 
  <%= for {key, value} <- @schedule do %>
    ...use key and value variables here...
  <% end %>
</p>
```