# Rendering img in an eex template: protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a project display page that displays text correctly:

```
<p><%= @post.body %></p>

<%= @post.title %></h1>
```

I want to display a user uploaded pic.

I tried:

```
<img src="<%= @post.project_pic %>"/>
```

which returns:

```
protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{file_name: "pexels-photo-144322 (1).jpeg", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2017-08-06 14:05:26>}
```

This shows me the pic has uploaded and is stored in the database.

I added inspect:

```
 <img src="<%= inspect @post.project_pic %>"/>
```

as per this answer:

[protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented Elixir Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971719/protocol-phoenix-html-safe-not-implemented-elixir-phoenix)

Which passes the compiler, but only displays a broken image icon.

**How is the pic stored?**

I have this in post.ex:

```
field :project_pic, Citybuilder.ProjectPic.Type
```

in stories.ex I have:

```
|> cast_attachments(attrs, [:project_pic])
```

in the latest migration file it's stored as a string:

```
 add :project_pic, :string
```

Maybe that's the error.

I'm not sure if the error is in my eex syntax, or somewhere deeper in the file structure.

Comment: How are you computing and storing `project_pic`? You probably want `<%= @post.project_pic.file_name %>` if the image is in the same root path.

Comment: I updated my question to include more info. See "How is the pic stored?" If you want to know anything else, please ask.

Comment: `cast_attachments` means you're using `arc` and `arc_ecto`?

Comment: Yes we are using arc and arc_ecto

Comment: Does this work: `<img src="<%= Citybuilder.ProjectPic.url({@post.project_pic, @post}, :original) %>"/>`?

Comment: Oh my, yes it does. Thanks. I would never have figured that myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arc_ecto` defines a `url` function in your attachment module, which you can call to get the complete URL of the upload which can then be used as `src` in an `<img>` tag. The first argument is a tuple  of the attachment value and the whole model, and the second is the image size (`:original` is the original full size image). The following should embed the original full size image for you:

```
<img src="<%= Citybuilder.ProjectPic.url({@post.project_pic, @post}, :original) %>"/>
```

Check out the [documentation of arc_ecto](https://github.com/stavro/arc_ecto#usage) for more.